# accessing phonebook contact using phonegap on windows phone 8

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, windows-phone-8

i want to access phonebook contact from my address book in javascript only.i tried below function its is showing me the contact number as well as phonenumber but sometimes its showing and sometimes its not showing simply an empty page.pls check this code and tell me if anything wrong is there in this code.my aim is to get the list of phonebook contact on a page.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    loadPhoneContacts();
}

function loadPhoneContacts() {
    var options = new ContactFindOptions();
    options.filter = "";
    options.multiple = true;
    var fields = ["displayName", "name", "nickname", "phoneNumbers"];
    navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccessOfLoadContacts, onErrorOfLoadContacts, options);
}
// onSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current contacts
//

function onSuccessOfLoadContacts(contacts) {
    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
        alert(contacts[i].name.formatted);
        for (var j = 0; j < contacts[i].phoneNumbers.length; j++) {
            alert(contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].value);
            $("#contact").append(contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].value);
        }
    }
}
// onError: Failed to get the contacts
//

function onErrorOfLoadContacts(contactError) {
    alert('onError!');
}
```

and in my html page

```
 <div id="contact"></div>
```

pls correct me if any error is there.i m working with visual express 2012.

Comment: have you considered the case where the contact has no phonenumber! Here is a good example that shows how different cases with validation http://vicrandom.blogspot.ca/2014/04/simple-phonegap-indexhtml-file-to-show.html

Comment: @Kal thank u..kal for the link...will check it..